# Way to speed up .obj file loader for HalfEdge Mesh?

Tags: c++, opengl, wavefront

I am working on a 3D OpenGl (C++) application in which I have my own Mesh structure based on the Half-Edge data structure.   I want to build a simple way to load Wavefront obj files into my mesh structure.  Of course, I can do so naively line by line, but there has to be some more efficient way (I know professional applications aren't loading the file naively line by line, it would be too slow for millions of vertices).

Can anyone point me to a tutorial or an example of a really fast OBJ loader?  It would be preferable if it had something to do with a Half Edge data structure.

Edit:

There are two basic issue I am looking to get around

1) Avoid the general slowness of reading floating point numbers from a file

2) How do i intelligently determine the "adjacent" halfedge for each edge on the fly.  I am imagining some sort of hashing function to determine if the symmetric or next edge for the edge being created already exists and, if so, use that pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue loading OBJ files a while ago, albeit I was searching for shared vertices as opposed to edges. Since the file format itself contains no connectivity information the best way is use a `std::set`. Each time you want to add an edge to your data structure you can search the set to see if it already exists. Set searching is logarithmic in complexity so it scales well with the size of your data structure. The only way to avoid this that I can think of is to choose a file format that contains the connectivity information you need, or as Michael Slade suggested create your own format and conversion tool.

Comment: `std::unordered_set` will give you O(1) lookups.

Comment: True, but I tend to avoid hash maps when needing to insert or erase elements often. When reading in a lot of data your `std::unordered_set` (hash map) would need to rehash frequently, which is a pretty expensive operation. You could reserve the space if you knew how many primitives were shared, but OBJ files don't give you that. It would be interesting to see which container performs best for different file sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Reading and decoding ascii files is slow, particularly if the files have a million floating point numbers to convert.

My idea: write a program in any language you desire, to translate the .obj files to a binary format your program can read more-or-less directly into memory.  Then run that program on the .obj files you want to load and have your program load the translated files.

For extra points, you could have your opengl program do this translation on-the-fly and cache the results, checking file modification times and updating the cache as necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by this?  Wouldn't that program just do the same work you're trying to avoid?

Comment: yes but it then you can do it ahead of time rather than have the program do it every time it runs.

Comment: I need to load any OBJ file while my program is running.  The issue is not the cost of reading the numbers, it is how to link the faces intelligently.

Comment: Are you talking about collapsing coincident vertexes into a single entry? Or something else?

Comment: Firstly collapsing vertices.  Second (this will make more sense if you are familiar with the half-edge data structure) I need to find the "symmetric" edge of each edge as I go through the file.  Aka at the point where two faces meet, there is an edge that should be represented by two half edges.

Comment: This sounds like it is amounting to a lot more than simply loading a .obj file for display.  Please amend your question. do you simply want to be able to display objects defined by .obj files? or something more sophistocated?

Comment: ie for what purpose do you want to compile the half-edge structure?

Comment: You're right.  My main question is about the HalfEdge, not the File IO.